# Start 2 application windows 8 batch

Tags: windows, windows-8, batch-file, scripting

I'm attempting to run two applications at the same time in Windows 8 via a batch file.

The standard way is:

```
START "NOTEPAD++" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
START "MACTALK" "C:\Program Files (x86)\JVL\MacTalk\MacTalk.exe"
```

This works in Windows 7, but when I move this script to Windows 8, Notepad.exe will start, but the second program never will.

Comment: Stupid question:  is the path to Mactalk valid on your Windows 8 machine?  Also, what happens if you `REM` out the first line, does the second line work?

Comment: If a rem the first line the second line does not work. It will still hang there. This example is lifted from my windows 7 machine, the identical structure exists within windows 8." Why?

Comment: UAC may be involved.  Knowing the exact programs would help - someone may use them and have an idea.

Comment: @foxidrive The 2 programs in question are jBEAM a german data acquisition system. And a proprietary application used to automatically fetch data from the FLUKE multimeter. Neither I can give away. Both accept command line arguments (optionally). Also UAC isn't an issue in windows7, and neither trigger a UAC warning in windows 7 or 8.

Comment: MACTALK actually does trigger a UAC warning in win7, and the script still executes.

Comment: Do you have Windows 8 `RT`? Otherwise you can check: `START "" "MACTALK" "C:\Program Files (x86)\JVL\MacTalk\MacTalk.exe"`

Comment: This is windows8 x86_64.

Comment: Have you tried my command?

Comment: Windows cannot find "mactalk", if I repeat for both, both error

Comment: @Valarauca    Ok, I own 8_64 and can check it out, it `mactalk` is downloadable. Btw. if you write a comment for an other user, put his nick name in your comment (like me), otherwise the system doesn't send a notification.

Comment: Some applications don't trigger a UAC warning when UAC is reduced - but it will still run correctly when run in an admin console.  Open an admin console and try your batch file to test this.

Answer (score 0):

you could try for example

Start Firefox&notepad

this works fine in win 7
I do not have win 8 to test this but as batch or CMD it should work.
Hope this helps.